# best way to select rows that has no one to many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select all rows of the table PERSON that has no records into DOCUMENT table that have the primary table as FK.

What could be the better for me? LEFT JOIN? NOT IN? Any other solution?

Here's the simple scheme:

`PERSON`:

```
personId
personName
personSex
```

`DOCUMENT`:

```
documentId
FK_Person
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `left join` and check if the link to the other table failed (`is null`)

```
select p.*
from person p
left join document d on p.personId = d.fk_person
where d.fk_person is null
```

See [this explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: thank you I forget that simple join ^^ thanks for the link too :-)

Answer (score 2):

try using `not exist` or `left join` :

```
select P.* 
from   PERSON P left join DOCUMENT D on P.personId = D.FK_Person
where  D.FK_Person is null
```

OR

```
select * from PERSON P 
where not exists (select 1 from DOCUMENT D where P.personId = D.FK_Person)
```